# Confused with Def Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, boolean, var

```
def yesno(endwhat):
    end = False
    while not end:
        ok = input("<Y/N>")
        if ok.upper == 'Y' or ok.upper == 'N':
            if ok.upper == 'Y':
                end = True
                endwhat = True
        else:
            print("Enter only <Y/N>")
    return(ok)
```

This Doesn't Work, It Just Repeats even when I put Y or N.
I think the problem is when I enter a var in 'endwhat' it doesn't change it to True.
Any Help is Truly Appreciated.
Thanks...

Comment: Seems like you are never reading from your 'endwhat' argument, which means that your function will not execute any differently depending on the value of 'endwhat'. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do u mean `ok.upper()` ?

Comment: If your input is `N`, your loop will also never end

Comment: Print `ok` and see that it includes a trailing newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put () to string function.

```
def yesno(endwhat):
  end = False
  while not end:
    ok = input("<Y/N>")
    if ok.upper() == 'Y' or ok.upper() == 'N':
        if ok.upper() == 'Y':
            end = True
            endwhat = True
    else:
        print("Enter only <Y/N>")
  return(ok)
```

Answer (score 0):

.upper() is a function, and all functions must contain a '()' for any parameters(if there are any). Otherwise they are taken to be default values mentioned. you have forgotten to put '()'. the right version would be-

```py
def yesno(endwhat):
  end = False
  while not end:
    ok = input("<Y/N>")
    if ok.upper() == 'Y' or ok.upper() == 'N':
        if ok.upper() == 'Y':
            end = True
            endwhat = True
    else:
        print("Enter only <Y/N>")
  return(ok)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot () for upper.
You can also use the code as following:

```
def yesno(endwhat):
  end = False
  while not end:
    ok = input("<Y/N>").upper()
    if ok == 'Y' or ok == 'N':
        if ok == 'Y':
            end = True
            endwhat = True
    else:
        print("Enter only <Y/N>")
  return(ok)
```

Comment: How is this answer different from previous answers?

Comment: You used .upper() in if statements but I used it in input statement.